# ValueError in string to datetime conversion

Tags: python

I am trying to convert strings (which I have in a list) to datetimes.
I tried this:

```
import datetime

list = [
    '12-October-2014-18:30',
    '12-October-2014-19:30',
    '12-October-2014-20:00',
    '12-October-2014-20:30',
    '13-October-2014-00:30',
]

for item in list:
  item_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%m-%B-%Y-%H-%M")
  print item_time
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '12-October-2014-18:30' does not match format '%m-%B-%Y-%H-%M'
```

I dont see the Error, can somebody help please?

Comment: `%m` should be `%d`, see [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @behzad.nouri: Please add your comment as a solution

Comment: @JohnB: `%m` matches *"Month as a zero-padded decimal number"*, so with `%m-%B` you have *two* fields for the month and *none* for the day of the month

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two things wrong.

for `'%m-%B-%Y-%H-%M'`, your date should be: `'12-October-2014-18-30'`

In some you have `12th` where it should just be `12` and in all of them you have `18:30` but need it to be `18-30`

Comment: That is still not enough because of `th` present after dates.

Comment: thanks, I made a type. I only have 12, not 12th.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I accounted for the `th`.

Comment: @JohnB then in that situation it's just the way you're formatting the time

Comment: @mattm I guess I missed it somehow. ;-)